# Verify Leibniz integral rule

Tags: calculus, integration

We have the integral equation $$\int_{0}^{x}\left(1+x+e^{x-t}\right) y(t) \mathrm{d} t=g(x), \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1\tag{1}$$
By using Leibniz integral rule, we have that $$g'(x)=(2+x)y(x)+\int_{0}^{x}(1+e^{x-t})y(t)\mathrm{d}t \tag{2}$$
Where $y$ and $g$ are chosen to satisfy the condition of Leibniz integral rule.
My question is that how to show if $g(x)$ satisfies equation $(2)$ then $y(x)$ satisfies equation $(1)$. In other words, how to prove $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$

Answer (score 2):

This comes straightaway from Leibniz rule. Not sure of the original proof (if that traces all the way back to Leibniz himself), but seems like a direct consequences of Chain rule.
Let 
\begin{equation}
g\left(x,a(x),b(x) \right)  = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{f(t,x) dt }
\end{equation}

Note that, Let $p(x) =\int_{x}^{C} {f(u) du} $ and  $q(x) =\int_{C}^{x} {f(u) du} $, where $C$ a constant, it is easy to verify the following. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{d x} p(x) &=& - f(x) \\
\frac{d}{d x} q(x) &=&  f(x)
\end{eqnarray*}

Using the Chain rule of integration

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{d x} g\left(x,a(x),b(x) \right) &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g\left(x,a(x),b(x) \right) +  \frac{\partial}{\partial a} g\left(x,a(x),b(x) \right)  \frac{d a}{d x} +  \frac{\partial}{\partial b} g\left(x,a(x),b(x) \right)  \frac{d b}{d x} \\
&=&  \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(t,x) dt }  - f\left(a(x),x\right) \frac{d}{d x} a(x) +  f\left(b(x),x\right) \frac{d}{d x} b(x)  \label{eqn1}
\end{eqnarray}

In the running example, $a(x)=0, b(x)=x, f(t,x) =\left(1+x + e^{x}  e^{-t}  \right) y(t)$, we will have  the above equation simplifies to,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{d x} g\left(x,a(x),b(x) \right) &=&  \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(t,x) dt }  - f\left(a(x),x\right) \frac{d}{d x} a(x) +  f\left(b(x),x\right) \frac{d}{d x} b(x)  \\
&=&  \int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( 1+x+ e^{x}  e^{-t} \right) y(t)   dt }  - \left(1+x+ e^{x}  e^{0} \right) y(0)   \frac{d}{d x} 0 +  \left(1+x+ e^{x}  e^{-x}\right) y(x)   \frac{d}{d x} x  \\
&=&  \int_{0}^{x}{ \left( 1+ e^{x}  e^{-t} \right) y(t)   dt }+  \left(1+x +1\right) y(x)  \\ 
&=&  \left(2+x\right) y(x) +   \int_{0}^{x}{ \left( 1+ e^{x-t}  \right) y(t)   dt }.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems that you prove $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$. What I'm asking is the proof of $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$